# Modifying ArraySlice with replaceSubrange

Tags: arrays, swift

While trying to correctly implement MergeSort algorithm in Swift for [RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#Swift) (which lists a very inefficient solution currently), I found a strange behavior. Since MergeSort requires recursively passing an array to a function, my most efficient implementation so far passes not the array itself (which cannot be passed by reference easily, it seems), but ArraySlice view of that array.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice) of ArraySlice seems to point out that ArraySlice does not store its data and merely provides a "view" of an underlying array:

> The ArraySlice type makes it fast and efficient for you to perform operations on sections of a larger array. **Instead of copying over the elements of a slice to new storage, an ArraySlice instance presents a view onto the storage of a larger array.** And because ArraySlice presents the same interface as Array, you can generally perform the same operations on a slice as you could on the original array.

However, modifying ArraySlice with `replaceSubrange` or setting its elements, does not seem to affect my original array. Like in this example:

```
// Create an array
var arr = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 5)
print("array:",arr)     // original array

// Modify its ArraySlice
var slice = ArraySlice(arr)  // or arr[0..<arr.count]
slice.replaceSubrange(1...3, with: [1,2,3])
slice[4] = 4
print("slice:",slice)   // slice preserves all the changes
print("array:",arr)     // but original array is not modified

// Modify Array directly
arr.replaceSubrange(1...3, with: [5,6,7])
print("array:",arr)     // this time it is modified
```

Output:

```
array: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
slice: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
array: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
array: [0, 5, 6, 7, 0]
```

As you can see, modifying ArraySlice makes changes to it, but doesn't modify my original array, as I expected.

The question is, why does it happen? And what is the underlying storage for my modified ArraySlice? In particular, where the element `4` gets stored?